# Rename subsection format

Tags: sectioning, abnt

I'd like to change the format of the subsection in my document. 1.1 instead 1.0.1 as shows the figure below. My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    %english,           % idioma adicional para hifenização
    french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
%   brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    english,
    brazil,
    ]{abntex2/abntex2}

\usepackage{abntex2/abntex2-cin-ufpe}


\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.2} %para customizar o espaço entre as linhas das tabelas


\usepackage{pdfpages} %para incluir pdf como páginas

\usepackage{cmap}               % Mapear caracteres especiais no PDF
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
%\usepackage{indentfirst}       % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
%\usepackage{color}             % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
\usepackage[versalete,alf,abnt-and-type=e,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-etal-cite=3]{abntex2/abntex2cite} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,noredefwarn]{glossaries}
\usepackage{acronym}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
  \glossarystyle{super}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}

  % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {
    \begin{longtable}
        {L{0.2\textwidth}L{0.8\textwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}
  }%
}

\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{rotating} %rotates the figures, page
\usepackage[ruled,titlenumbered,linesnumbered,lined,boxed,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace} 

% Command Definition
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\setcounter{corollary}{1}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

\newcommand{\bsl}{\boldsymbol}
\newcommand{\prob}{\mathds}
\newcommand*\NewPage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\input{custom}

\makeindex


\input{others/acronimos}

\makenoidxglossaries
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{\textit{#1}  
\glsseelist{#2}}

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % remove trailing dot
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\input{others/glossaries}
\input{packages}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is done by using `\subsubsection{Motivation}` directly below `\section{Introduction}, without using any `\subsection` commands. But how is the numbering supposed to go exactly in this scheme? Is the next section `1.0.2`? What about after `1.0.9`, should it be `1.0.10`? When do you go to `1.1.x`, if at all? If this should be a manual decision, how and where should this be indicated in LaTeX code? Does a two-part section number occur anywhere (`1.0` or `1.1` etc)? If so, where? If not, why do you want to use a three-part number instead of a two-part number?

Comment: In fact, I did remember to use the `\subsection`. This solves the problem. Thanks!